# How do I upload a document from a web form to google docs?

Tags: python, google-docs-api

I'm writing a web aplication for users to upload documents on their computer to google docs, and download them.
It seems that google docs python API requires that the files for upload be stored locally on the server running the aplication.
How do I allow users to upload documents using a web form?

Comment: there is an example in docs how to do it: http://code.google.com/intl/pl-PL/apis/documents/docs/3.0/developers_guide_python.html#GettingStarted

Answer (score 0):

[Google Documents List Data API](http://code.google.com/intl/fr/apis/documents/docs/3.0/developers_guide_protocol.html#UploadingDocs) is a REST API, so you can use it in any language. You can use urllib2 or culrlib to make your HTTP requests, or use http://code.google.com/intl/pl-PL/apis/documents/docs/3.0/developers_guide_python.html#GettingStarted